# Facebook image not returning proper size

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access profile pictures of friends using `Facebook Graph API` having size of `48 x 48` in android application. [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/#sizes)

But it seems to give different results.

Eg.

1. `http://graph.facebook.com/aliabush/picture?width=48&height=48`
2. `http://graph.facebook.com/aakash.parekh.77/picture?width=48&height=48`
3. `http://graph.facebook.com/adityaamarathe/picture?width=48&height=48`

All three result into different sizes. How to resolve this issue? I know we can use `type=square`, but I want to get it with size `48 x 48`

Thanks in advance

Comment: resize Bitmap after downlod

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I can do it by specifying the height width in dp instead of wrap content. But the issue is FB gives images in px